# CUDA run solution with three .cu files

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I have CUDA 8 and Visual Studio 2015.

I would like to run three cuda files from "CUDA by example" book (example is histogram).

I have three .cu files:

```
hist_cpu.cu
hist_gpu_gmem_atomics.cu
hist_gpu_shmem_atomics.cu
```

I would like to run these at the same time. All three files include `book.h`.

How to compile these and show results from the three files in one output? Is it possible?

Comment: One way to do this would be to write a wrapper script that would compile and run each file, concatenate their output, and then print it.

Comment: Have you got example for this or can you help me to write it?

Comment: I can write it in bash that will run on linux, but since you are using a Windows system, a bash script won't help unless you are using Cygwin. You can also use other scripting languages on Windows like Python, Perl or PHP for this purpose; if you do a google search for this, you should find many resources on how to do this.

Comment: CUDA is not related to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you're using CUDA with C++. Suppose you have 3 `.cu` files. Each file contains a kernel and a function that calls the kernel.

```
__global__
void testKernel1() {}

void func1()
{
    testKernel1<<<1,1,1>>>();
    printf("Called Kernel 1\n");
}
```

Then you have a `.cpp` file, which contains your `main` function. In this file include the 3 functions from the `.cu` files using `extern` keyword.

```
#include <iostream>

extern void func1();
extern void func2();
extern void func3();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    func1(); //calling func1 from 1st .cu file
    func2(); //calling func2 from 2nd .cu file
    func3(); //calling func3 from 3rd .cu file
}
```

Comment: .cu fiels have main function

Comment: @K.Kempski Rename those `main` functions to something else and if those functions take arguments then pass arguments to those functions from the `main` function in your `.cpp` file.

Comment: Now it output "cannot open file gcc.obj"

Comment: @K.Kempski Upload your 4 files to pastebin and upload the links here.

Comment: Join this chat room: `OpenCV Related` and lets talk. You've to do some work to get it working.

Comment: Ok, I joined to this chatroom